# Add HTML Value To JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, html

Ok.. So i have a html element that displays a current value, value is changed via range slider, i change the value of the html element using javascript with the following code:

```
hex_out = document.querySelector('#hex');
hex_out.value=rangeValue;
```

Which the above works fine, but recently I've needed to be able to add a bit of html code into `hex_out.value`

for example if i try

`hex_out.value="<font color='red'>"+rangeValue+"</font>"`

it will change `hex_out.value` to the code shown below

`<font color='red'>Range slider value</font>"`

which is obviously not what i'm trying to accomplish. How would i add html code to `hex_out.value` and have it display correctly?

Before anyone trys to say "This is a duplicate question", realize i've tried nearly ALL solutions shown on stack overflow with no luck

Comment: Please show more code? What is `#hex`? I suspect it is an `input` element? If so, you can't render HTML in an `input` element. It sounds like you want to do `hex_out.style.color = "red"`.

Comment: @RevTech i tested the code in your site, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify the color via the element's style property. Try the following:

```
hex_out.style.color = 'red';
```

If you need to add any HTML, then (assuming that the `hex_out` element is a container element, and not an `<input>` tag), you can assign the HTML to its `innerHTML` property like so:

```
hex_out.innerHTML = '<strong>This is a <em>formatted</em> value.</strong>';
```

Another edit: It looks like you're using an `<output>` element, which doesn't accept child elements as far as I know. In this case, you'll likely want to use a regular `<div>` or `<span>` tag instead of `<output>` and then update its value manually as your sliders move using the `innerHTML` property described above.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've updated my answer. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
var hex_out = document.querySelector('#hex'),
    rangeValue = document.querySelector('#val');

rangeValue .addEventListener('input', function () {
  hex_out.innerHTML = "<font color='red'>"+rangeValue .value+"</font>";  
}, false);
```

```html
<input type=range id=val>
<span id=hex>50</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is the thing normally expecting from javascript. I consider you want to change html of an existing element not value. If it is you can use below code:

```
hex_out. innerHTML ="<font color='red'>"+rangeValue+"</font>"
```

Existing fiddle link [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0b95xf3x/)

Tested and works:

```
function setColor() { debugger;
  Rval = parseFloat((r_out.value / 255.00).toFixed(3));
  Gval = parseFloat((g_out.value / 255.00).toFixed(3));
  Bval = parseFloat((b_out.value / 255.00).toFixed(3));
  hex = "R: " + Rval + " " + "G: " + Gval + " " + "B: " + Bval;
  var r_hex = parseInt(r.value, 10).toString(16),
    g_hex = parseInt(g.value, 10).toString(16),
    b_hex = parseInt(b.value, 10).toString(16),
    hex1 = "#" + pad(r_hex) + pad(g_hex) + pad(b_hex);
  body.style.backgroundColor = hex1;
  hex_out.innerHtml = hex + [
'<br/><font size="1px">GSC RGB Selector</font>'
].join('#hex');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulty arose because you put an obsolete [font tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) in the [output tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) which only accepts "phrasing content". The font tag is not supported in HTML5 and not on the list of phrasing content elements.

As @Mark said, a simple div will do if you require HTML to be rendered.